# Round robin style load balancing, or other simply forms of load balancing

Tags: proxy

this is the question:
if a user had multiple servers, and wanted each request to select a server at random or on purpose, how would one do so? without changing urls and attempting to keep it simple? im aware of it with DNS, but not on tor.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done either on the HiddenService layer via [NGinx](https://nginx.org/) or using [OnionBalance](https://onionbalance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) . If the application is a website or web service - both tools can be combined for a better results